# Kendo Grid Row Grouping Not Working

Tags: html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo for the first time and am attempting to convert an HTML table to a Kendo grid. Upon initialization, I want the table to be grouped by a specific column and not be groupable by any other column. Below is a contrived example of a table of cars to be grouped by the car's make which demonstrates how I am attempting to group by a specific column upon initialization.

This attempt does not cause the table to be grouped. I know the kendoGrid call is working, because if I set groupable to true I am able to group by any column via drag and drop, but the initial grouping still does not occur. I suspect that somehow the group field "make" is not being tied to my make column, but examples I've seen seem to indicate this can be accomplished using data-field as I have done.

```
<table id="carsGrid">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Color</th>
            <th data-field="make">Make</th>
         </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>2010</td>
            <td>Red</td>
            <td>Dodge</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2014</td>
            <td>Blue</td>
            <td>Ford</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2016</td>
            <td>Black</td>
            <td>Dodge</td>
        </tr>   
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And in the document's ready function:

```
$('#carsGrid').kendoGrid({
    datasource: { group: { field: "make" } },
    groupable: false //I do not want grouping on other columns
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found some solution for your problem: Check this example http://dojo.telerik.com/OhEta

You should add `data-groupable="false"` attribute in `<th>` element:

```
 <thead>
     <tr>
        <th data-field="year" data-groupable="false">Year</th>
        <th data-field="color" data-groupable="false">Color</th>
        <th data-field="make">Make</th>
     </tr>
 </thead>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I am already able to group by a column via the drap and drop functionality that your solution has. My issue is that I want the table to be automatically grouped by make as soon as the page renders without any action from the user.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an html `<table>` you can setup the columns and their values in the javascript.

First you can replace your entire `<table></table>` section with:

`<div id="grid"></div>`.

Then in your document's ready function, you can throw your values for each column into an array:

```
var productsArray = [{Year: 2010, Color: "Red", Make: "Dodge"},
                     {Year: 2014, Color: "Blue", Make: "Ford"},
                     {Year: 2016, Color: "Black", Make: "Dodge"}]
```

And update where you set the kendo grid with:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
      data: productsArray,        
      group: {field: "Make"}
    },
    columns: [
      { field: "Year" },
      { field: "Color" },
      { field: "Make" }
    ]
});
```

[Click Here](http://dojo.telerik.com/oWaXi) for a working example that you can test with.